# Trying to remove rows with zeros in Pandas, getting KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

I am pretty new to Python and Pandas in general, apologies for the noob question.

I am trying to sort out the values that I read from a csv file by removing the items with less than 0.01 in them. Unfortunately, I've been either getting `KeyError`s all day, or the error is `"TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'"` and I'm at my wits end.

My code looks like this:

```
def get_aws_account_usage_charges(df):
    df_gb = df[['item_type', 'item_currency', 'item_description', 'item_price', 'item_quantity', 'charge_amount', 'item_amount']].groupby(['item_type', 'item_currency', 'item_description', 'item_price'], dropna=False).sum().reset_index()
    format_aud = lambda conv: '%.2f' % (conv['item_amount'])
    format_usd = lambda conv: '%.2f' % (conv['charge_amount'])
    df_gb['charges_aud'] = df_gb.apply(format_aud, axis=1)
    df_gb['charges_usd'] = df_gb.apply(format_usd, axis=1)
        
    print(df_gb['charges_aud'])
    
    return df_gb.sort_values(by='charge_amount', ascending=False)
```

The return looks like this:

```
0      1.11
1     17.00
2      0.70
3      0.59
4      0.00
5      0.05
6      2.45
7      6.00
8      0.00
9      0.00
10     0.00
11     3.60
12     0.13
13     0.00
14     0.01
15     0.10
16     0.04
17     0.00
18     0.00
19     0.01
20     0.01
21     0.10
22     0.01
Name: charges_aud, dtype: object
```

Any idea how I could remove the zeroes before I do my return, so when I do `print(df_gb['charges_aud'])`, it'd look like this?

```
0      1.11
1     17.00
2      0.70
3      0.59
4      0.05
5      2.45
6      6.00
7      3.60
8      0.13
9      0.01
10     0.10
11     0.04
12     0.01
13     0.01
14     0.10
15     0.01
```

Comment: `df_gb[df_gb['charges_aud'] >= 0.01]` will leave you with rows that satisfies the condition `df_gb['charges_aud'] >= 0.01`

Comment: exactly as Raymond has said, just filter the dataframe fur values gather than 0.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, @RaymondKwok and @Umar.H! Unfortunately, when I tried it, the error was ```"TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'"```. I was hoping to sort them out before I do my return.

Comment: `astype` can change datatype. so, `df_gb[df_gb['charges_aud'].astype(float) >= 0.01]`. change `>=0.01` to `>0` if needed

Answer (score 0):

```
...
df_gb = df[['item_type', 'item_currency', 'item_description', 'item_price', 'item_quantity', 'charge_amount', 'item_amount']].groupby(['item_type', 'item_currency', 'item_description', 'item_price'], dropna=False).sum().reset_index()

df_gb = df_gb[df_gb.item_amount > 0]

format_aud = lambda conv: '%.2f' % (conv['item_amount'])
format_usd = lambda conv: '%.2f' % (conv['charge_amount'])
...
```